# How to distinguish outgoing and incoming photon in Feynman Diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, feynman-diagrams

So, the feynman rules for QED claims that:

For an incoming photon, we add a $\epsilon^{\mu}(k)$ factor,

For an outgoing photon, we add a $\epsilon^v(k')^*$ factor.

But i am not sure how do we distinguish an outgoing and incoming photon! I mean, suppose this 1rst order diagram of Compton scattering

[image]

My guess is that we would have something like this:

$$-iM \propto \epsilon_v(k')^* \epsilon^\mu(k)$$

BUt it seems that the term is actually proportional to

$$-iM \propto \epsilon_v(k') \epsilon^\mu(k)^*$$

Why? Why is the left photon an outgoing photon?

Comment: Your textbook should have explained the direction of time assumed by the diagrams in the book. Each book assumes a different time direction. Also, if you really understand the framework of QFT, the really important thing is not which are inputs and which are outputs, but rather how many external legs there are, because there is a symmetry to convert inputs to outputs and vice-versa.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent The books is generally assuming time going horizontally from left to right. So what you mean with your last sentenceis that it does not matter which one is complex conjugate, only that one of the polarization vector is?

Comment: No, I mean that if you figure out the S matrix or any single Feynman diagram with n external legs, then you can move input to output external legs and vice versa, with some small changes, a bit like how you wrote the complex conjugation to get the contribution. If your left photon is the outgoing photon, I think your book actually takes time going vertically upwards.